# setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale - Alternatives when trying to scale an UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I use the following to scale a view to 3x its original size:

```
[pageShadowView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale (3, 1)];
```

I would like to have a method which tests if my UIView (pageShadowView) is already scaled - and in that case I'd like to divide it by 3, so that it is back to its normal size.

I can't think of any method which would do that. So I thought it may be perhaps best to test if my UIPageView has a certain dimension, and if it doesn't to rescale it to its original size.

**So my question is if there is a method to scale an UIView to a certain width and height which is not relative (i.e. 3x its size), but expressed in pixel (e.g. 200 pixel x 300 pixel).** I couldn't find any thing in the documentation which is, to be honest, a bit over my head when it comes to the section on CGAffineTransform.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if your view is scaled we just need to check if its `transform` is not an identity transform.

```
BOOL isScaled = ! CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(pageShadowView.transform);
```

One should note, that this check will only be valid if you do not use any other kinds of transform i.e. rotation or translation.

Scaling `UIView` to certain width and height is easy as well:

```
CGFloat yourDesiredWidth = 200.0;
CGFloat yourDesiredHeight = 300.0;

CGAffineTransform scalingTransform;
scalingTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(yourDesiredWidth/pageShadowView.bounds.size.width, 
                                              yourDesiredHeight/pageShadowView.bounds.size.height);
pageShadowView.transform = scalingTransform;
```

It is important to check `UIView`'s `bounds` instead of `frame`, because `frame` is not valid when `UIView` is transformed.